# NtWriteFile - ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (error 87)

Tags: c, winapi

I made a simply wrapper for NtWriteFile and I'm encountering an error coming from `NtWriteFile`. Here is my code:

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(HANDLE hFile, PVOID lpBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten) {
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK IOBlock;
    NTSTATUS Status = NtWriteFile(hFile, NULL, 0, NULL, &IOBlock, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToWrite, 0, NULL);

    DWORD A = RtlNtStatusToDosError(Status); // just to get the error code

    if (Status == STATUS_PENDING) {
        Status = NtWaitForSingleObject(hFile, FALSE, NULL);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(Status)) Status = IOBlock.Status;
    }
    if (NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
        *lpNumberOfBytesWritten = IOBlock.uInformation;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

The value of `A` after setting a breakpoint on the line after is `87` which points to `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETR`, question is which paramter is invalid? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you *don't* check `A`, does it seem to work? You should only check error codes if a function actually fails.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: [`NT_SUCCESS()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-ntstatus-values).

Comment: i guess that you create asynchronous file handle - without `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_[NO]NALERT` option or if you use `CreateFile` - with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`. in this case the the *ByteOffset* is mandatory parameter and can not be 0

Comment: The most likely parameter that can be wrong in that call is the file handle. Where is the mcve?

Comment: almost 100% because *ByteOffset* is zero

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not relying on `A`, LOL. It's there for you guys :) 

@HarryJohnston NT_SUCCESS returns TRUE if Status is >= 0. However if it fails, the error code can be obtained with RtlNtStatusToDosError.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan File handle is valid, its 0x00000068 (a invalid file HANDLE == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) The file is opened for writing. FILE_CREATE and FILE_SHARE_WRITE with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL.

Comment: @AMG63 - read my comment - and use direct `ByteOffset` - file is created for asynchronous I/O ? yes?

Comment: @RbMm I actually forgot to set the `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT`flag in my CreateFile wrapper. The byte offset was obviously specified 8D I was just silly to miss this. Thanks for the tip, it works fine now.

Comment: No, that is not the only invalid handle value.

Comment: I'm aware, but for the most case. The other invalid handle values, I'd rely on the PEB LastError or in this case (RtlNtStatusToDosError) the TEB LastStatus...

Comment: if you plan use `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` - no sense check for `STATUS_PENDING` and conditional wait after `NtWriteFile` - you never got this status in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you prepare for `STATUS_PENDING` in your code and wait after `NtWriteFile` in this case - i assume that you use file (*hFile*) opened or created for asynchronous I/O. otherwise call `NtWaitForSingleObject` after `NtWriteFile` have no sense. so i assume that you not use either `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` or `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` when you call `NtOpenFile` or `NtCreateFile` (or you use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in `CreateFile` call)

in case asynchronous I/O the *ByteOffset* (penultimate) parameter is mandatory. from windows source code:

> **ByteOffset** - Specifies the starting byte offset within the file to begin
>           the write operation.  If not specified and the file is open for
>           synchronous I/O, then the current file position is used.  **If the
>           file is not opened for synchronous I/O and the parameter is not
>           specified, then it is in error.**

and piece of code, where you fail in kernel:

```
} else if (!ARGUMENT_PRESENT( ByteOffset ) && !(fileObject->Flags & (FO_NAMED_PIPE | FO_MAILSLOT))) {

    //
    // The file is not open for synchronous I/O operations, but the
    // caller did not specify a ByteOffset parameter.  This is an error
    // situation, so cleanup and return with the appropriate status.
    //

    if (eventObject) {
        ObDereferenceObject( eventObject );
    }
    ObDereferenceObject( fileObject );
    return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;

}
```

so we need or always direct use *ByteOffset* if we opened or created for asynchronous I/O. or if we use synchronous file handle - the `NtWriteFile` is **never** return  `STATUS_PENDING` and operation always complete synchronously - this is by design. so no any sense check for `STATUS_PENDING`  in this case. you can drop this check and `NtWaitForSingleObject` (also wait on hFile is possible but not very correct if multiple operations on file in concurrent)

---

and from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567121(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If the call to **ZwCreateFile** set either of the *CreateOptions*
>   flags, *FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT* or *FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT*,
>   the I/O Manager maintains the current file position. If so, the caller
>   of **ZwWriteFile** can specify that the current file position offset
>   be used instead of an explicit *ByteOffset* value. This specification
>   can be made by using one of the following methods:
>
> - Specify a pointer to a LARGE_INTEGER value with the HighPart member    set to -1 and the LowPart member set to the system-defined value
>     FILE_USE_FILE_POINTER_POSITION.
> - Pass a **NULL** pointer for *ByteOffset*.

despite nothing explicitly said about what will be otherwise (no *FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT* or *FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT* flag) - possible understand that in this case  I/O Manager **not** maintains the current file position and we **can not** specify that the current file position offset be used - only explicit *ByteOffset* value must be